# What is the antonym of 丁寧語? either "dictionary form" or "conversational form" of a verb?

Tags: words

食べます、飲みます、読みます are the _ 丁寧語 _ forms of 食べる、飲む、読む。

But, how do I call the "forms" for 食べる、飲む、読む？
食べる、飲む、読む are the _ ??? _ forms of 食べます、飲みます、読みます。

I think of 食べる、飲む、読む as being the *dictionary* form or the *conversational* form.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/what-do-i-actually-call-familiar-or-friendly-language/24613#24613